# Linear least square of two variable function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to fit the data of the form $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ where $f=f(x,y)$.

My idea is to minimize $\sum\limits_{i}(z_i-f(x_i,y_i))^2$.

Function $f$ in $x$ and $y$ is linear.

$f(x,y)=a_1y-a_2y^{2/3}-\dfrac{a_3x(x-1)}{y^{1/3}}-\dfrac{a_4(y-2x)^2}{y}$

Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

If you set $f_1(x,y) = y, f_2(x,y) = -y^{\frac23}, f_3(x,y) = -\frac{x(x-1)}{\sqrt[3]y}, f_4(x,y) = -\frac{(y-2x)^2}y$ then
$$f(x,y) = a_1 f_1(x,y) + a_2 f_2(x,y) + a_3 f_3(x,y) + a_4 f_4(x,y)$$
The least-squares approach now goes as follows: Set up the equations
$$Fa = z$$
Where $a\in\mathbb R^4$ are the unknown coefficients, $z = (z_i)_i$ is the vector of values and $F_{i,j} = f_j(x_i,y_i)$ is the matrix of template function values at the $i$-th coordinates. The system can then be solved using regular least-squares methods or by computing
$$a = (F^TF)^{-1} Fz$$

Answer (score 1):

So you want to minimize

$S = \sum\limits_{i}(z_i-f(x_i,y_i))^2$

So lets find turning points by differentiating with respect to the $a_j$ co-efficients

Turning points will be where the derivative is zero

$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_j} = 0$

$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial a_j}  = 2 \sum\limits_{i} (z_i-f(x_i,y_i))(-1) \frac{\partial  f(x_i, y_i)}{\partial a_j} = 0$

$ \sum\limits_{i} (z_i-f(x_i,y_i)) \frac{\partial  f(x_i, y_i)}{\partial a_j} = 0$

In our case we end up with four equations from each of our four $a_j$'s

$ \sum\limits_{i} (z_i-f(x_i,y_i))y_i = 0$

$ \sum\limits_{i} (z_i-f(x_i,y_i))(-y_i^\frac{2}{3}) = 0$

$ \sum\limits_{i} (z_i-f(x_i,y_i)){\frac{-x_i(x_i - 1)}{y_i^\frac{1}{3}}} = 0$

$ \sum\limits_{i} (z_i-f(x_i,y_i))(-\frac{(y_i - 2x_i)^2}{y_i}) = 0$

Sub in the expression for $f$ into these equations and simplify them.

Then distribute the summation sign over the expressions.

This will reveal four linear simultaneous equations with four unknowns ($a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$)

These can be solved using Gaussian elimination.